# How to find the instantaneous axis of velocity?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I read the similar topics here and on the web, but non of those seem to help me. I know that the instantaneous axis of zero velocity lies on the **xy** plan, but I don't understand why it lies on the **y** axis?

[image]

Comment: Isn't the rod from the center of the disk to the origin always along the $y$ axis? That is, don't the $x$ and $y$ axes rotate around the $Z$ axis along with the disk?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri That's got have to be it, yes indeed those axis rotate around the z and Z, so it remains on y :) but I think this is not gonna be true later in time because $\omega$ is the angular velocity according to the fixed coordinate system.